# How to handle exceptions matching to separate function in scala

Tags: scala

The below is just an example to represent my case of usage,

Suppose there is a function,

```
def getSomeValue(request:Int):Unit = {
    val retry =  try {
        doSomething
        true
    }
    catch {
      case _:NullPointerException => false
      case _:IndexOutOfBoundsException => false
      case _:Exception => true
    }
    if(retry)
      getSomeValue(request)
  }
```

I want to handle all the exceptions in a separate function. Like below,

```
def handleException = {
    case _:NullPointerException => false
    case _:IndexOutOfBoundsException => false
    case _:Exception => true
  }
```

And tried using it in the function as,

```
def getSomeValue(request:Int):Unit = {
    val retry =  try {
        doSomething
        true
    }
    catch handleException
    if(retry)
      getSomeValue(request)
  }
```

The compiler thrown couple of errors,

> 1. Method apply is not a member of type Any
> 2. Method isDefinedAt is not a member of type Any

Could some one please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can do what you want if you replace the imperative `try / ctach` statement with the functional [**Try**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html) data structure / adt / effect / monad / burrito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%C3%ADa-su%C3%A1rez) for helping me on this,

I am able to achieve this by how he said,

```
def getSomeValue(request:Int):Unit = {
    val result =  Try(doSomething)
    val retry = result match {
      case Success(_) => false
      case Failure(exception) => handleException(exception)
    }
    if(retry)
      getSomeValue(request)
  }

  def handleException(exception: Throwable) = exception match {
    case _:NullPointerException => false
    case _:IndexOutOfBoundsException => false
    case _:Exception => true
  }
```

Any other answers also welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

There is function `recoverWith` in `scala.util.Try` for such cases. It takes partial function which handle specified exceptions. If your `Try` will fall you can specify retry inside this function.

For example:

```
import scala.util.{Failure, Try}

def getSomeValue[A](doSomething: => A): Try[A] =
  Try(doSomething).recoverWith {
    case t: NullPointerException => Failure(t)
    case t: IndexOutOfBoundsException => Failure(t)
    case _: Exception => Try(doSomething) // retry doSomething
  }
```

this function returns `Try[A]` after retry and you can handle errors on the upper-lever.